# Сreating a file with text input into it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm started learning nodejs and faced the following problem. It is necessary to create a file in which there is conditionally nothing, and when it is created, a greeting is displayed, with a suggestion for the subsequent input of text (any) which, in turn, will be saved in the created file. Text input continues until the thread is stopped via ctrl+c, and when pressed, displays the farewell text (sry my eng ^_^)

Gave a couple of examples

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });

fs.appendFile('server.txt', greeting, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Appended!');
});

const greeting = rl.question('Hi user, what your name? ', (answer) => {
  console.log(`Hi ${answer}, nice to meet you! Сontinue...`);
  rl.on('line', (input) => {
    console.log(`Your thoughts: ${input}`);
  });
});

let data = rl.on('line', (input) => {
  console.log(`Received: ${input}`);
});

let hi = 'Hi user, what your name? ';

newFunction();
function newFunction () {
  fs.writeFile(
    'greteng.txt',
    hi,
    {
      encoding: 'utf8',
      flag: 'w',
      mode: 0o666,
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log('File written successfully\n');
        console.log('The written has the following contents:');
        console.log(fs.readFileSync('greteng.txt', 'utf8'));
      }
    },
  );
}

newFunction(data);
```

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, you want to constantly be receiving text from the terminal and feed that into the file?

Comment: Yes, that's what i need